# Construtores Estáticos

Tags: c#

Por que não posso declarar uma função construtora estática?
Exista algum problema com relação ao contexto?

Comment: Pode sim, Algum código que está fazendo e não deu certo?

Comment: Na verdade é uma dúvida. Vou dar um exemplo: Se eu declarar ele como static Method(){}, qual a diferença para um construtor que não seja estático?

Comment: Qual é a dúvida? O descrito parte de uma premissa errada.

Comment: Entendo. Corrigi meu comentário acima.